# How to transform the output of FactorInteger to a traditional format?

Tags: output-formatting

I changed the FactorInteger output to a format which is more suitable to my needs.

I used:

```
f[x_] := Array[x[[1]] &, x[[2]]]
fac[n_] := Flatten[Map[f[#] &, FactorInteger[n]]]
```

Example:

```
fac[24] yields {2,2,2,3}
```

Now, for presentation purposes only, I would like

```
{2^3, 3}
```

as the result of the function fac.

I tried several things such as:

```
HoldForm[2^3], which yields 2^3 as I would like, but
```

using the function

```
g[x_] := HoldForm[x[[1]]^x[[2]]] in fac instead of f
```

gives unexpected results.

How can I present the results of FactorInteger n as

```
{p1^a1, p2^a2, ... ,pn^an} i.e. ( 2^2, 5^3, 7 } ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Inactive[Power] @@@ FactorInteger[24] /. Inactive[Power][a_, 1] :> a
```

[image]

Your `fac[24]` could be written as

```
Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[24]]
```

[image]

To not show the ^ symbol:

```
Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[24] /. Superscript[a_, 1] :> a
```

[image]

Comment: Much better already but I don't want the ^ symbol in 2^3, I want the 3 lifted to the exponent place $2^3$ ( should have used Latex in question I suppose ). I tried adding //TraditionalForm but that did not work.

Comment: See update -------------------------------------

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorInteger.html#8661):

```
CenterDot @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[7!]
```

[image]

Though `CenterDot` does not work well for prime powers:

```
CenterDot @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[5]
```

[image]

If this is a problem, you could just define your own:

```
myCenterDot[e_] := e
myCenterDot[args__] := CenterDot[args]
```

Now it works fine:

```
myCenterDot @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[5]
```

[image]

You could do something similar for `Superscript` if you don't want to see `1` in the exponents.

Comment: Or without the dot, and using `Times` only for formatting:  `Times @@ Map[Superscript[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, FactorInteger[630]]`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) and `\[CenterDot]`:

```
fi[u_] := 
 Row[Riffle[
   Cases[FactorInteger[u], {a_, b_} :> 
     If[b == 1, a, Superscript[a, b]]], "\[CenterDot]"]]
```

For example:

```
Table[{j, fi[j]}, {j, {5, 10, 12, 84, 420, 1260, 3780, 5040}}] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and useful, thanks.