# Pretty printing of factorization output

Tags: grid-layouts, display

I want to create a table of factorization of certain numbers $f(n)$ with traditional pretty printing output (more or less same as what is used to display in textbooks). For example consider

```
FactorInteger[Table[n!, {n, 0, 5}]]
```

standard output is

```
{{{1, 1}}, {{1, 1}}, {{2, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}}}
```

and the so-called traditional output is some kind of matrix-looking format, with first column the base and the second column the exponent.

How do I create a suitable display output as in

$$\begin{array}{cc} 
 \text{N} & \text{factorization of N!} \\  \hline
 0 & 1 \\ \hline
 1 & 1 \\ \hline
2  & 2 \\ \hline
3  & 2, 3 \\ \hline
4 & 2^3, 3 \\ \hline
5 &  2^3, 3,5 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The lines and heading etc. are not the important aspects, the easily readable output is.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103845/how-to-transform-the-output-of-factorinteger-to-a-traditional-format/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = FactorInteger[Table[n!, {n, 0, 5}]];

leftCol = Prepend[Range[0, Length[data] - 1], "N"];

rigthCol = Prepend[
   Row[HoldForm[#]^#2 & @@@ {##}, ","] & @@@ data, 
   "factorization of N!"
];

Grid[
  Transpose[{leftCol, rigthCol}], 
  Alignment -> {{Right, Center}}, 
  Dividers -> {False, {False, {True}}}, 
  BaseStyle -> 25
] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A bit differently:

```
list = FactorInteger[Table[n!, {n, 0, 5}]];
r    = Range[0, 5];
fac  = Map[Apply[HoldForm[#1^#2] &, #, {1}] &, list]
```

> {{1^1},{1^1},{2^1},{2^1,3^1},{2^3,3^1},{2^3,3^1,5^1}}

```
Transpose@{r, Row /@ fac} // 
  TableForm[#, TableDepth -> 2, TableAlignments -> Center, 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"N", "factorization of N!"}}] & // Framed
```

[image]

Should be done with `Grid`, as "while `TableForm` allows you to create tables, it does not support the extensive styling options that are available to `Grid`" [[ref]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PutHeadingsInATable.html), but that has been already [shown by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133085/22013).

Answer (score 3):

```
fun[x_] := 
 Row@Riffle[
   MapThread[If[#2 == 1, #1, HoldForm[#1^#2]] &, 
    Transpose[FactorInteger[x]]], "\[CenterDot]"]
Grid[Prepend[{#, fun[#!]} & /@ Range[0, 10], {"N", 
   "Factorization N!"}], Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> 20]
```

[image]