# Flatten a list without increasing the length of the array

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to make a list of rules where every integer is replaced with a string of it's prime factorization:

$$
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
         1\to \left\{1^1\right\} \\
          2\to \left\{2^1\right\} \\
          3\to \left\{3^1\right\} \\
          4\to \left\{2^2\right\} \\
          5\to \left\{5^1\right\} \\
          6\to \left\{2^1,3^1\right\} \\
          7\to \left\{7^1\right\} \\
          8\to \left\{2^3\right\} \\
          9\to \left\{3^2\right\} \\
          10\to \left\{2^1,5^1\right\} \\
          11\to \left\{11^1\right\} \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
$$

However, I don't want the rules to be lists. I want 6 to map to $2^1\cdot 3^1$... and so on. How do I accomplish this?

The factorization code is:

```
FactorInt[x_]:=Module[{},
(Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[x])
]
```

Comment: Analogously to: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133083/5478?

Comment: What's `Collatz`? Is that really needed here?

Comment: It isn't. I'm just going to ask another question later since this one is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
factorInteger[x_Integer] := Row[Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[x]]
factorInteger /@ Range@10 // Column
```

[image]

To get the results in a list of rules you can use:

```
With[{numbers = Range@10},
  Thread[Rule[numbers, factorInteger /@ numbers]]
  ] // Column
```

[image]