# Numerical output using Select and FactorInteger

Tags: functions, function-construction, factorization, refactoring

I have concocted a function from other peoples examples to find the powers of two in a prime decompostion, in the example below its $2^2=4$ gives {2,2}.

```
Select[FactorInteger[4], #[[1]] == 2 &] (*#[[1]] means part 1 {1,2}*)
```

Now this is all well and good (I think!) but I want the output in a format I can use numerically like 4 instead of {2,2}.

How might I achieve this simple task N[]
does not work.

This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103845/how-to-transform-the-output-of-factorinteger-to-a-traditional-format) is not what I'm looking for as it does not provide a usable numerical output but just changes format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

It uses your code and just adds a bit to get the numeric result for you

```
n = 2^3*5*7*11;
Power @@ Select[FactorInteger[n], #[[1]] == 2 &][[1]]

(* 8 *)
```

The `[[1]]` at the end gets rid of the extra layer of `{}`

The `Power @@` turns `{2,3}` into `Power[2,3]` and the result is 8

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but perhaps you could use `IntegerExponent`.

```
primePower[n_,p_]:=p^IntegerExponent[n,p]
```

where `n` is the number you want factored, and `p` is the prime of interest. For your example,

```
primePower[4,2]
```

returns 4.